# Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.1 installation failed

Tags: azure, azure-storage

When installing the Azure SDK 2.7, I encounter that Web Platform Installer fails to install the Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.1.

In the error log, I can find the following messages:

```
CAQuietExec:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.1.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  Error: Cannot create database.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an addendum, if the above doesn't work, stop both the MSSqlLocalDB and the v11.0 and delete them using the appropriate sqllocaldb commands, THEN the install will work.

Comment: this was my case on Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator v4.2. Deleted both LocalDB instances, reinstall and works :D

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer from my own to this one since it is applicable for most cases, though it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

delete file C:\Users\(Your user account)\AzureStorageEmulatorDb41.mdf and AzureStorageEmulatorDb41_log.ldf

Reinstall again.

Comment: I recall trying this, but that didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I found deleting the 2 files as recommended above, and then force a init of the storage emulator worked for me:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>sqllocaldb info
    MSSQLLocalDB
    ProjectsV12
    v11.0

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -forcecreate -autodetect
    Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.1.0.0 command line tool
    The storage emulator was successfully initialized and is ready to use.

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>
```

No reinstall or removal of SQL instances/SSDT required.

Answer (score 1):

After looking up other instructions to fix the issue [like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822372/Windows-Azure-Storage-Emulator-failed-to-install), I noticed that when I execute the command

```
C:\Users\Bart>sqllocaldb info
MSSQLLocalDB
v11.0
```

It returns two databases. Looking up more information, it looks like one of the databases keeps running.

```
C:\Users\Bart>sqllocaldb info "v11.0"
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.3000.0
Shared name:
Owner:              Machine\Bart
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    3 Aug 2015 10:01:14 AM
Instance pipe name:

C:\Users\Bart>sqllocaldb info "MSSQLLocalDB"
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:
Owner:              Machine\Bart
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    3 Aug 2015 10:02:16 AM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#D4336BDE\tsql\query
```

I've tried to stop, delete and create the databases again, per the linked article that the databases may be corrupt. I've also tried to stop the instances and then re-run the installation, but noticed that always the v12 version was running again.

This triggered me that having two versions of LocalDB might be the problem.

Uninstall **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (12.0.41025.0)** (note, your localization version may differ) - that's SQL Server 2014 LocalDB.

Then re-run the installation and it should succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with 4.2. I deleted the files stated above as well as AzureStorageEmulatorDb42.mdf and AzureStorageEmulatorDb42_log.ldf and then the install worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with v4.5 and deleting MSSqlLocalDB and v11.0 didn't work.

I noticed I had **web companion** installed.

When I uninstalled it, and then reinstalled the storage emulator, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `"CAQuietExec:  Error: Cannot create database."` Check to see if you have *Lavasoft Web Companion* installed.

As another user suggested uninstall it and try to install Azure Storage Emulator again.