# Cannot install Azure Storage Emulator 4.1

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2013, installation, azure-storage-emulator

Hoping someone can help with this - I've spent a full day attempting to resolve. I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, followed by the Azure SDK. All the Azure SDK Components installed, except for the storage emulator, which in my case is version 4.1 Here is the error log which may hold some clues.

```
=== Logging started: 03/08/2015  20:17:34 ===
Action 20:17:34: INSTALL. 
Action start 20:17:34: INSTALL.
Action 20:17:34: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 20:17:34: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 20:17:34: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:34: PrepareDlg. 
Action start 20:17:34: PrepareDlg.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Bigger textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 19 pixels height.
Action 20:17:34: PrepareDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 20:17:34: PrepareDlg. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:34: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 20:17:34: AppSearch.
AppSearch: Property: DOTNET4FULL, Signature: DOTNET4FULLInstalledSearch
AppSearch: Property: LOCALDB11INSTALLED, Signature: LocalDB11Search
AppSearch: Property: LOCALDB12INSTALLED, Signature: LocalDB12Search
AppSearch: Property: SQLEXPRESSVERSION, Signature: SQLExpressSearch
Action ended 20:17:34: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:34: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 20:17:34: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 20:17:34: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:34: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 20:17:34: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 20:17:34: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:34: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:17:34: CostInitialize.
Action ended 20:17:35: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:35: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:17:35: FileCost.
Action ended 20:17:35: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:35: SetREINSTALLMODE. 
Action start 20:17:35: SetREINSTALLMODE.
Action ended 20:17:35: SetREINSTALLMODE. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:35: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:17:35: CostFinalize.
Action ended 20:17:35: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:35: CustomWelcomeEulaDlg. 
Action start 20:17:35: CustomWelcomeEulaDlg.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 14 pixels height.
Action 20:17:35: CustomWelcomeEulaDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 20:17:37: CustomWelcomeEulaDlg. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:37: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 20:17:37: ProgressDlg.
Action 20:17:37: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 20:17:37: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:37: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 20:17:37: ExecuteAction.
Action 20:17:39: INSTALL. 
Action start 20:17:39: INSTALL.
Action 20:17:39: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 20:17:39: AppSearch.
Action ended 20:17:39: AppSearch. Return value 0.
Action 20:17:39: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 20:17:39: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 20:17:39: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
Action 20:17:39: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 20:17:39: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 20:17:39: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 20:17:39: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 20:17:39: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:17:39: CostInitialize.
Action ended 20:17:39: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:17:39: FileCost.
Action ended 20:17:39: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: SetREINSTALLMODE. 
Action start 20:17:39: SetREINSTALLMODE.
Action ended 20:17:39: SetREINSTALLMODE. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:17:39: CostFinalize.
Action ended 20:17:39: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: SetCommandForRunInitialize. 
Action start 20:17:39: SetCommandForRunInitialize.
Action ended 20:17:39: SetCommandForRunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: InstallValidate. Validating install
Action start 20:17:39: InstallValidate.
Action ended 20:17:39: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:39: InstallInitialize. 
Action start 20:17:39: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 20:17:40: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
Action start 20:17:40: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 20:17:40: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
Action start 20:17:40: ProcessComponents.
Action 20:17:40: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
GenerateScript: Updating component registration
Action ended 20:17:40: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
Action start 20:17:40: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 20:17:40: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
Action start 20:17:40: RemoveRegistryValues.
Action ended 20:17:40: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
Action start 20:17:40: RemoveShortcuts.
Action ended 20:17:40: RemoveShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RemoveFiles. Removing files
Action start 20:17:40: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 20:17:40: RemoveFiles. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: InstallFiles. Copying new files
Action start 20:17:40: InstallFiles.
InstallFiles: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
Action ended 20:17:40: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RunInitialize. Initializing the Storage Emulator
Action start 20:17:40: RunInitialize.
1: Initializing the Storage Emulator 
Action ended 20:17:40: RunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
Action start 20:17:40: CreateShortcuts.
CreateShortcuts: Shortcut: Creating shortcuts
Action ended 20:17:40: CreateShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
Action start 20:17:40: WriteRegistryValues.
WriteRegistryValues: Key: Writing system registry values, Name: , Value: 
Action ended 20:17:40: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RegisterUser. Registering user
Action start 20:17:40: RegisterUser.
Action ended 20:17:40: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: RegisterProduct. Registering product
Action start 20:17:40: RegisterProduct.
RegisterProduct: Registering product
Action ended 20:17:40: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
Action start 20:17:40: PublishFeatures.
PublishFeatures: Feature: Publishing Product Features
Action ended 20:17:40: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
Action start 20:17:40: PublishProduct.
PublishProduct: 
Action ended 20:17:40: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action 20:17:40: InstallFinalize. 
Action start 20:17:40: InstallFinalize.
Action 20:17:40: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {2B9D6EDC-B349-5E7B-AB9A-2FAD4E908326} 3: 02:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Storage Emulator\InstallPath 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {5430E0E9-7AB7-50E9-9748-D577B5F485B8} 3: 02:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1\DisplayName 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {D6EF4D0E-9249-538F-BCA7-9B6FE369941D} 3: 01:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Storage Emulator\ 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {84F54093-B880-50C9-858C-C1A877AC52D6} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Release Notes.url 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {A24144CE-C842-5114-86B2-73633606DB12} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\License.rtf 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {DF9AD451-5F04-50F8-94AA-957EC90DA832} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\StartStorageEmulator.cmd 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {B5FDA61D-8F49-5986-9CE4-6CAEF3895817} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {EC492ED1-611E-5956-A3FC-AA6E766637CA} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {349D3C99-F1E4-50CF-87CC-D13B7C28C88C} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Services.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {2FB2A960-F788-5BB8-9AB9-346B3ADC2B2F} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Storev4.0.2.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {EAEB16CF-3CEA-5FE0-A700-8ED6A77EAB73} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {3C3678F2-CC37-5BEC-B8BA-EA05A7D34630} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {333DAEDB-9307-5643-8498-256F8C66E832} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {90F85106-6838-5E29-BE37-685473590198} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {B18125A9-F1F8-52BE-8098-B798F3C1221D} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {08219C28-EEF9-561B-9AF9-5973C02A4C31} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Data.Services.dll 
1: {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2} 2: {C340E337-4F53-5A33-8B67-F1446F0B7C94} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\System.Spatial.dll 
Action 20:17:40: InstallFiles. Copying new files
InstallFiles: File: Release Notes.url,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 69
InstallFiles: File: License.rtf,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 16941
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 660144
InstallFiles: File: AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 3995
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Data.OData.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 1520304
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Services.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 1301208
InstallFiles: File: System.Spatial.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 118448
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 86744
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Storev4.0.2.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 392920
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Data.Services.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 911536
InstallFiles: File: AzureStorageEmulator.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 175320
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 659120
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 75992
InstallFiles: File: StartStorageEmulator.cmd,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 70
Action 20:17:40: RunInitialize. Initializing the Storage Emulator
CAQuietExec:
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 20:17:42: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action 20:17:42: Rollback. Rolling back action:
Rollback: Initializing the Storage Emulator
Rollback: Copying new files
Rollback: Updating component registration
Action ended 20:17:42: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {CF5CD495-AEDE-42DA-B7CF-A70D398D4E6A}
Property(S): RunInitialize = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
Property(S): DOTNET4FULL = 4.5.51641
Property(S): LOCALDB11INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): LOCALDB12INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(S): StorageEmulatorMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): STORAGEEMUDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(S): REINSTALLMODE = amus
Property(S): AzureMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Azure\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): AZUREDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\
Property(S): MICROSOFTSDKSDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Users\garveyj\Desktop\
Property(S): MSIRMSHUTDOWN = 1
Property(S): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
Property(S): ProductCode = {5F57531E-3891-43D6-9B59-489B7A592CE2}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1
Property(S): ProductVersion = 4.1.6848.8
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERVERSIONDETECTED;OLDEMULATORPACKAGEDETECTED;OLDERVERSIONDETECTED
Property(S): WixPdbPath = o:\bttemp\551729\obj.amd64fre\services\xstore\rdpackages\storageemulatorpackage\objfre\amd64\en-us\MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.wixpdb
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\garveyj\Desktop\log.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {8B374F42-A082-4F5F-B99B-6817934B52B9}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\garveyj\Desktop
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 03/08/2015  20:17:45 ===
MSI (c) (44:54) [20:17:45:165]: Product: Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1 -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (44:54) [20:17:45:165]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1. Product Version: 4.1.6848.8. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Also, after using the msi installed instead of the web installer (which seems to crash right at the end), I was able to get a look at the verbose logging (tried to pull out relevant bits here as log was huge):

```
=== Verbose logging started: 03/08/2015  22:25:19  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (F4:08) [22:25:19:608]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (F4:08) [22:25:19:608]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:624]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:624]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:624]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:624]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:733]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\temp\MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:733]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\temp\MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi has a digital signature
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:19:827]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\temp\MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.

MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:876]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Release Notes.url;   To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:876]: Source for file 'emulatorrelnoteslink.txt' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: Release Notes.url,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 69
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:907]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=License.rtf,SourceCabKey=EULA.rtf,DestName=License.rtf,Attributes=512,FileSize=16941,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=512919968,HashPart2=-491928154,HashPart3=-598440689,HashPart4=1216904583,,)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:907]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\License.rtf; To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:907]: Source for file 'EULA.rtf' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: License.rtf,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 16941
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:954]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=vb-oyuxd.dll|Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll,SourceCabKey=fil47CB5E34FDBDCB1498AC8BB0147AC42D,DestName=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=660144,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=5.6.1.61768,Language=0,InstallMode=62914560,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:954]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll;  To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:23:954]: Source for file 'fil47CB5E34FDBDCB1498AC8BB0147AC42D' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 660144
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:094]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=7rxshsmz.con|AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config,SourceCabKey=fil5721F24B0854A1A2955B13D07EBD8F01,DestName=AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config,Attributes=512,FileSize=3995,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=-1421539733,HashPart2=-752243163,HashPart3=194679837,HashPart4=-732217664,,)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:094]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config; To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:094]: Source for file 'fil5721F24B0854A1A2955B13D07EBD8F01' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 3995
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:110]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=s3odyzgw.dll|Microsoft.Data.OData.dll,SourceCabKey=fil6BBEC58DFB23D2A68DBC1559A327DF05,DestName=Microsoft.Data.OData.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=1520304,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=5.6.1.61768,Language=0,InstallMode=62914560,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:110]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll;    To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:110]: Source for file 'fil6BBEC58DFB23D2A68DBC1559A327DF05' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Data.OData.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 1520304
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:188]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=aps4uleh.dll|Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Services.dll,SourceCabKey=fil7230A7B11B0323B15C5E247EE4DA33F4,DestName=Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Services.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=1301208,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=4.1.6848.8,Language=0,InstallMode=62914560,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:188]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Services.dll; To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:188]: Source for file 'fil7230A7B11B0323B15C5E247EE4DA33F4' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: Microsoft.Azure.DevelopmentStorage.Services.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\,  Size: 1301208
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:266]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=fsf9fsr3.dll|System.Spatial.dll,SourceCabKey=fil8DEA54FB17E8256A62B8591FFA8C308D,DestName=System.Spatial.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=118448,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=5.6.1.61768,Language=0,InstallMode=62914560,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:266]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\System.Spatial.dll;  To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file

Action 22:25:24: RunInitialize. Initializing the Storage Emulator
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:24:610]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=RunInitialize,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect)
MSI (s) (E4:94) [22:25:24:673]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIF8D2.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
MSI (s) (E4:28) [22:25:24:673]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (E4:28) [22:25:24:688]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 8796 (0x225C).
MSI (s) (E4:C4) [22:25:24:735]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (E4:C4) [22:25:24:751]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

Action ended 22:25:30: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Executing op: Header(Signature=1397708873,Version=500,Timestamp=1191424812,LangId=1033,Platform=0,ScriptType=2,ScriptMajorVersion=21,ScriptMinorVersion=4,ScriptAttributes=1)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=0,Argument=1033)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=1,Argument=Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1)
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Executing op: RollbackInfo(,RollbackAction=Rollback,RollbackDescription=Rolling back action:,RollbackTemplate=[1],CleanupAction=RollbackCleanup,CleanupDescription=Removing backup files,CleanupTemplate=File: [1])
Action 22:25:30: Rollback. Rolling back action:
Rollback: Initializing the Storage Emulator
MSI (s) (E4:98) [22:25:30:304]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=RunInitialize,Description=Initializing the Storage Emulator,)

MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:31:507]: Product: Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1 -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:31:523]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.1. Product Version: 4.1.6848.8. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:31:523]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:31:523]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (F4:D4) [22:25:31:523]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 03/08/2015  22:25:31 ===
```

I appear to have two instances of localDB installed - MSSQLLocalDB and V11.0.

Also, does the blatant lack of info mean anything?:

```
Action 20:17:40: RunInitialize. Initializing the Storage Emulator
CAQuietExec: <<--- Other users received more logging here...
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xe0434352: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 20:17:42: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action 20:17:42: Rollback. Rolling back action:
Rollback: Initializing the Storage Emulator
Rollback: Copying new files
Rollback: Updating component registration
```

Hoping someone out there has had a similar problem and can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I've not had problems installing, but faced few problems starting the emulator, I figured out later that the port Emulator is trying to use is blocked by BitTorrent, can you try this.

Comment: Thanks Sri, it's a company laptop - all torrent software is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely be due to the two instances of localDB. If the localDB instance is corrupted the installation fails. Try recreating the local DB instance as described in these articles:

[Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.1 installation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778626/windows-azure-storage-emulator-4-1-installation-failed?answertab=active#tab-top) 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822372/Windows-Azure-Storage-Emulator-failed-to-install